# Python 3 Creating visual representations

Tags: python, graphics

I'm going to be creating visual representations of numeric sums, which can have contents such as:
constants, functions, operators and arguments.
I would like to be able to represent each of those things seperatly with adjustable properties such as line width, size, font size, colour etc.

My program loops round a math problem, and solves it - however I need to draw how to solve the math problem step by step, using boxes and lines (maybe animation? however static boxes and lines are okay)

I've already tried using tkinter however it doesn't seem to have the functionality I require.

I have no knowledge with graphical representation in any computing language **so could anyone suggest something I could do this with?** (I have to use a python back-end as I already have the code to calculate the math problem in python).
The output would preferbly be a window upon running the .exe

here is an example of the type of visulisation that I need to draw.
(each picture is a different example with modified atributes such as line width etc)
the numbers are passed in via variables and so are the operators - however the lines should be automatically placed.

[image]

Comment: Without an example, it's hard to guess what you precisely are looking for: a picture is word a 1000 words here. One of the default Python plotting libraries is [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html), which when installed with LaTeX on the system, can generate math formulas in the graphs.

Comment: @Evert I've edited the original post with a picture! I'll have a look at matplotlib, however I don't need graphs

Comment: Ah, that helps a lot. Yes, matplotlib is probably not what you want, though it can do those things (it just requires quite a bit of manual work).

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be interactive, you could always write a [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) file, which can then be opened in any number of programs (including most web browsers). You wouldn't need any extra modules or libraries to accomplish this, just open a file and start writing text to it. You could even achieve animation later I believe. A quick google turned up [svgwrite](http://pythonhosted.org//svgwrite/) which is a python module intended to make writing to SVG files easier, but SVG as is, is a pretty simple XML format so you don't technically even need another module for it (this just ought to make it a bit easier).

Comment: Fantastic, I've heard a number of colleagues talk about SVG - I'll google that and have a look to see if it'll be suitable!

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this earlier, but [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is probably the easiest way for you to do this. There's even an example [very similar to what you're doing](http://www.graphviz.org/content/Genetic_Programming) although admittedly it's not actually evaluating the expression. There are apparently several python bindings available as well (I'm not qualified to recommend one though).